# Can Twilio play aifc audio file?

Tags: audio, twilio

I tryed to play an audio file with in the `.aiffc` format. But when I call to that twilio number, it says "application error." The Twilio call log shows a 502 error for that audio url.

Does Twilio support `aifc` audio files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Twilio support's that file type. See their documentation on the `<Play>` verb

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play

As of 26th Feb 2013, Twilio supports the following audio MIME types for audio files retrieved by the `<Play>` verb:

> ```
> MIME type     Description
> audio/mpeg    mpeg layer 3 audio
> audio/wav     wav format audio
> audio/wave    wav format audio
> audio/x-wav   wav format audio
> audio/aiff    audio interchange file format
> audio/x-aifc  audio interchange file format
> audio/x-aiff  audio interchange file format
> audio/x-gsm   GSM audio format
> audio/gsm     GSM audio format
> audio/ulaw    μ-law audio format
> ```